# size_t, void* and hbitmap data type equivalents in MIDL

Tags: c++, windows, midl

What MIDL data types should I use to declare interface method parameters of C++ data types like `size_t`, `void*`, `HBITMAP` and other types of winapi handles (`HANDLE`, `HFONT`, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`size_t` is implementation defined, but using Visual Studio's CRT, it's an unsigned 32-bit integer when compiling for 32-bit architectures and an unsigned 64-bit integer when compiling for 64-bit architectures. You'll want to use `unsigned __int3264`, which is 32 bits on a 32-bit architecture and 64 bits on a 64-bit architecture.

`void*` is another platform dependent type. MIDL provides a `void*` type, but it's only a 32-bit pointer regardless of the targeted address size, I believe. You may want to use the `unsigned __int3264` type, instead.

MIDL provides types with the same names as the various handle type, though I'm not sure if all handle types are included; I know `HBITMAP` is, at least.

Comment: void* is 64 bit in MIDL if targeted 64-bit platform.